# Scroll Lateral con CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, bootstrap-5

**Resumen**

Estoy intentando poner un scrol lateral para visualizar cartas de boostrap, pero no logro hallar el problema (El problema es que las cartas no me las ajusta para ver lateralmente)

Estoy utilizando la ultima version de bootstrap

```css
#myWorkContent{
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row ">
        <div id="myWorkContent">
            <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
            <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
            <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No olvides agregar en el snippet el enlace a Bootstrap, y agregar además la etiqueta [bootstrap], junto con la versión que estás utilizando.

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres que esté ese scroll?

Comment: la carta de boostrap deberia estar a la derecha de la imagen de los gatos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería usar el `grid` de 12 columnas de `bootstrap`. Ya tienes un `row` que envuelve todo el contenido, lo que sigue es usar `class="col-#"` donde **#** es la cantidad de columnas que debe ocupar cada `div` interno.

Cabe resaltar que esto se ajustará automáticamente de acuerdo al tamaño de la apantalla, por lo que, es posible que debas ejecutar el snippet en pantalla completa.

```css
#myWorkContent {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8" id="myWorkContent">
    <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
    <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
    <a href="assets/work/1.jpg"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200/" height="190"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```